# Process to load elevation data into Oracle 11G

Tags: data, elevation, oracle-spatial, loading

We have the National Elevation data set from USGS and considering loading it into Oracle (11G) database.
Can someone help with the process/steps?

Comment: As this is a question and answer site it is est to phrase as a question.

Comment: There are many questions to be answered by yourself (or your entity) prior to doing the work.  
First off, the NED data is considered a raster datatype.  
You will need to decide the use scenario and client access inside Oracle.  
That will help to determine the data format to be used inside oracle.  
Which will also narrow the choices for loading it into oracle.  

I hope someone else will take interest and answer or provide insight/alternatives to loading. such as using it as a service in whatever application you have planned.